# Dax : Ranking of values per day

Tags: dax, powerquery

I have a list of values that change each day :

[image: ![enter image description here]

What i want is a ranking for each day for these 3 values, like this (the 31/08/2020, value one was the biggest, value 2, second etc ...)

[image]

I tried to use the rankx function in the following way but as i'm new to this, i'm struggling to get anywhere close to a result :

=RANKX(ALL(table[Date];table[val]);CALCULATE(SUM(table[Values]));0)

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so after some (much) more time and research, here is what works for my case :

```
=RANKX (
CALCULATETABLE (
    VALUES ( table[val]);
    FILTER (
        ALLSELECTED ( table );
        table[Date] = IF ( HASONEVALUE (table[Date] ); VALUES ( table[Date])) )
    );
CALCULATE ( SUM ( table[Values] ) );
;
DESC;
DENSE)
```

A bit more complicated than what i thought but this works.

Answer (score 1):

```
RANKX(CALCULATETABLE(table; ALLEXCEPT(table;table[date])); table[Values];table[Values];0)
```

Try this, you can follow below [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9c68ee65-29fa-4032-84a2-8d71f61c6999/rankx-partition-by-in-dax?forum=sqlkjpowerpivotforexcel) to get more details

Comment: hey there, thanks but i didnt work. i'll post an answer as i found the solution